# SharePoint Survey Notifications

Tags: sharepoint-server, survey

Is there a way to automate notifying users of a survey automatically? Also, is there a way to set an expiration date on the survey as to when it may no longer be filled out?

Answer (score 0):

We need a little more information but at first sight I would use a cookie to verify if the user as done the survey. As per when the survey is done I would use a JavaScript redirect based on the date.

Comment: Surveys come with the function to restrict the number of responses per user to one.